# Is there a way to join two objects in python in such a way that all values in one of the objects are duplicated for each value in the other object

Tags: python, dataframe, object

I am working with two python objects. One is a list of names, called "People", the other is a list of dates, called "Dates". They are structured as below:

[image: Image with the structure I am looking for]

I have tried a few ways to get this to work using joins with the following coming the closest:

```
Names_Dates = pd.concat([Names, Dates], axis=1, join='inner')
```

However, this does not achieve the goal of replicating the Dates for each value in Names. Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: the desired outcome doesn't seem to be necessarily stored in a DataFrame object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
names = ['John', 'Mary', 'Alex']
dates = ['1/13/2019', '1/14/2019', '1/15/2019']

print(list(itertools.product(names, dates)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('John', '1/13/2019'), ('John', '1/14/2019'), ('John', '1/15/2019'), ('Mary', '1/13/2019'), ('Mary', '1/14/2019'), ('Mary', '1/15/2019'), ('Alex', '1/13/2019'), ('Alex', '1/14/2019'), ('Alex', '1/15/2019')]
```

If you want to iterate over the `name, date` tuples, you can do something like this:

```
import itertools
names = ['John', 'Mary', 'Alex']
dates = ['1/13/2019', '1/14/2019', '1/15/2019']

for name, date in itertools.product(names, dates):
    print(name, date)
```

**Output:**

```
John 1/13/2019
John 1/14/2019
John 1/15/2019
Mary 1/13/2019
Mary 1/14/2019
Mary 1/15/2019
Alex 1/13/2019
Alex 1/14/2019
Alex 1/15/2019
```